# Multisite with entirely different domains?

Tags: multisite

Just trying the multisite feature for the first time. The primary hostname is blog.domain1.com. When trying to create multiple sites, it only allows me to create XXXXX.blog.domain1.com. But what I really want is blog.domain2.com, blog.domain3.com, etc. All on the same Apache instance, same database, same IP.

Is that doable directly with WP? I could try some Apache rewrite wizardry, but it just seems ugly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As Chip said.. install WordPress MU Domain Mapping.

create a subdomain on each of the domains you want to connect. Point that subdomain to you server IP.

Use WordPress MU Domain Mapping and connect each subdomain you just pointed to your blog id..

Comment: forgot, WordPress MU Domain Mapping doesn't work on a shared hosting of course..

Comment: Is the expression "shared hosting" used in some kind of WP-specific way? Is this name-based virtual hosting? IP-based virtual hosting? Something else?

Comment: yep, virtual hosting service. This often means that you are sharing your IP nr with others and you can't redirect domains pointing to that ip nr. if you don't have full control over the server will say :)