# Multisite with Different Domains

Tags: multisite

This question is similar to [Multisite with entirely different domains?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/multisite-with-entirely-different-domains) which was not answered.  I am re-asking.

I want to host multiple domains using WP multisite, which is installed and working normally in "multiple subdomains" mode.  This creates multiple WP sites like

```
site1.domain.com
site2.domain.com
```

I want to use

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
```

I've tried the Wordpress MU domain mapping plugin but I'm not satisfied with its behavior.  This plugin seems to simply redirect the user, ie. the user enters

```
www.domain1.com
```

and the browser is sent to

```
site1.domain.com
```

I don't want the user to know they aren't on domain1.com.

I also tried setting up VirtualHosts in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName site1.domain.com
   ServerAlias domain1.com
   ServerAlias www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But this also seems to produce a redirect to

```
site1.domain.com
```

in the users's browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain mapping is the correct answer to your question, because that isn't how the domain mapping plugin works at all.

Take a look at http://ottopress.com. It really lives at http://ottodestruct.com/op/, but you wouldn't know it, would you? It's a domain mapped site on a multisite installation.

If you're getting a redirect to the wrong URL, check to be sure that you set up the new domain as the "primary" in the domain mapping. The primary one is the one that the others will redirect to.

Comment: This was the solution - the wrong domain was listed as the primary.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried the Wordpress MU domain mapping plugin but I'm not satisfied with its behavior. This plugin seems to simply redirect the user

Are you sure that your domains DNS changes propagated long enough? It can take up to 48hours sometimes.

Reason I'm asking is because I am using the same plugin on one of my Multisite installs and although the setup of it all is a bit more complicated than a single WordPress install, eventually you can get it to work without too much trouble.