# Multisite with different domain names

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

Let's say I have an `site1.example.wordpress.com` site, but instead I want me users to see (in their browsers) different link, e.g. `example.com`. I.e. when someone types `example.com` it would serve `site1.example.wordpress.com` but in browser it would display `example.com`.

I'm aware of [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/multisite-with-different-domains) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251116/how-to-use-wordpress-multisite-with-different-domain-names) solutions. However, I do not want to install the plugin, and the solution that suggests changing TLD in wordpress seems iffy (it's a good solution, that I keep seeing everywhere on the net). However, can a CNAME be used?

And if I add `example.com` as a CNAME, can I add it just as a `ServerAlias` (apache 2.4) in my existing vhost for multisite? Or should I make separate virtual host that would reverse proxy to `site1.example.wordpress.com`?

Comment: Your examples use wordpress.com. Are these sites on wordpress.com?

Comment: @JacobPeattie No. Just an example. I'm the root admin of a server, domains are different than the example domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Multisite can handle this without a plugin.

What you need to do:

*I'm assuming that your WP Multisite installation is at `example.wordpress.com` and your desired URL for the new site is `example.com`, per your question.*

1. Create the site in the Network Admin section on `example.wordpress.com`.
2. Select **Edit Site** on the newly-created site.
3. Change the **Site Address (URL)** to whatever you need it to be (in this case, `example.com`.

As long as the DNS resolves correctly, and your webserver knows that `example.com` is to be served by `example.wordpress.com` (eg, your `example_wordpress_com.conf` file in Apache has a line like `ServerAlias example.com`), you should now be able to go to `example.com` in your browser and have your new site appear.

[See this answer for a couple of screenshots.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184667/16121)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pat. In the mean time I was looking into reverse proxy option and CNAME, but both don't deal with dynamic nature of how a wordpress generates a page. Namely, all links within a page would point to the old domain. So changing the site URL in wp-admin is the only solution. The only problem is this: Will it break the site? So far I haven't got an answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299581/changing-multisite-url-after-the-subsite-has-been-in-use

Comment: If you've got command-line access to your server, you can use [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) to change all the links: something like [`wp search-replace [old-string] [new-string] --url={site-name} --dry-run`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) will show you what needs to be replaced, and then—if you're satisfied—you can run it again without the `--dry-run` flag.